# Como ejecuto una parte del código varias veces, pero que reemplace una variable en cada repetición?

Tags: python, json

Estoy escribiendo un script en Python que guarda imagenes de una API

- Mi problema es que necesito guardar 10 imagenes con el nombre: (Imagen_sat_0, Imagen_sat_1, Imagen_sat_2) y así sucesivamente hasta 10.
- Por lo tanto necesito crear un bucle que me cambie los indices en cada repeticion. Mi codigo es

```
imagenes_sat_0=(dados_imagenes_satelitales)[0]['base64']
imagen_base64_0=imagenes_sat_0.replace('data:image/jpg;base64,',' ')

imgdata = base64.b64decode(imagen_base64_0)
filename = 'Imagen_sat_0.jpg'
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
   f.write(imgdata)
```

Como verán, necesito que ese código se ejecute 10 veces, pero en todos los lugares que diga cero, sea reemplazado por su consecutivo en cada iteracion.

O sea

```
imagenes_sat_1=(dados_imagenes_satelitales)[1]['base64']
imagen_base64_1=imagenes_sat_1.replace('data:image/jpg;base64,',' ')

imgdata = base64.b64decode(imagen_base64_1)
filename = 'Imagen_sat_1.jpg'
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
   f.write(imgdata)
```

Así evito escribir 10 veces ese codigo con indices diferentes.

Comment: Lo suyo es tener una lista llamada `imagenes_sat` e ir añadiendo a esa lista cada imagen  con `imagenes_sat.append(imagen)`. Para acceder a cada elemento de la lista puedes hacerlo por su índice `imagenes_sat[0]`, `imagenes_sat[1]`, etc. Y naturalmente el índice puede ser otra variable (que se incremente en el bucle).

Answer (score 1):

Podrías crear el nombre del fichero de forma dinámica, no?

Es decir:

```
i = 0
while i < len(imagenes_sat):
    filename = 'Imagen_sat_' + str(i) + '.jpg'
    i = i + 1
```

De esta forma, generarías en cada vuelta un filename distinto, es decir:

```
filename = 'Imagen_sat_0.jpg'
filename = 'Imagen_sat_1.jpg'
filename = 'Imagen_sat_2.jpg'
```

Luego esos filenames ya puedes guardarlos en una lista, para trabajar con ellos más tarde. La propiedad 'imagenes_sat' del bucle sería un listado con tus imágenes

Comment: Cierto, estoy trabajando ahora mismo en Java y me he liado, gracias!

Comment: Probablemente me exprese mal en mi pregunta, en realidad tengo que reemplazar todas las variables donde tienen 0, eso incluye el nombre de la imagen, pero también el resto de variables. Como veras, en el código existen 6 variables que incluyen el cero. Una de ellas es, inclusive un indice del json ' [0] '  de la API. Se podria aplicar lo mismo? Agradezco mucho la respuesta