# ¿Cómo cambio nombre de una variable en Python?

Tags: python, variables

Quiero ejecutar un código 70 veces, pero cada uno con variables diferentes.

O sea, la idea seria mas o menos así:

```
nombre_X=(datos)[X]['archivo_json'] 
nombre_convertido_X=nombre_X.replace('remplazo','')
```

Observen donde esta el valor [X] tiene que ser reemplazado por 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9... y así hasta 70.

O sea

```
nombre_0=(datos)[0]['archivo_json'] 
nombre_convertido_0=nombre_0.replace('remplazo','')
```

```
nombre_1=(datos)[1]['archivo_json'] 
nombre_convertido_1=nombre_1.replace('remplazo','')
```

```
nombre_2=(datos)[2]['archivo_json'] 
nombre_convertido_2=nombre_2.replace('remplazo','')
```

.
.
.

```
nombre_70=(datos)[70]['archivo_json'] 
nombre_convertido_70=nombre_70.replace('remplazo','')
```

¿Cuál sería el método mas eficiente para realizar ese cambio de variable? y evitar escribir 70 veces ese código

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como ejecuto una parte del código varias veces, pero que reemplace una variable en cada repetición?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/394858/como-ejecuto-una-parte-del-c%c3%b3digo-varias-veces-pero-que-reemplace-una-variable)

Comment: Eso no se puede, usa 2 arreglos nombre[0],nombre[1], nombre[2].... nombre_convertido[0], nombre_convertido[1].....

Comment: Y aún si consiguieras lo que te propones ¿cómo usarías otra vez las 70 variables resultantes sin tener que volver a nombrarlas una a una? Idealmente deberías poder usarlas dentro de un bucle y no nombrándolas directamente. Pues eso precisamente son las listas. En vez de `nombre_X` tendrías `nombre[X]` como ya te dije en un comentario a [tu otra pregunta similar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/394858/como-ejecuto-una-parte-del-código-varias-veces-pero-que-reemplace-una-variable)

Answer (score 6):

Aunque es una mala idea hacerlo de esta forma, ya que es preferible usar diccionarios, podrías hacer uso del método [locals](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/locals#:~:text=The%20locals()%20method%20updates,%2C%20methods%2C%20classes%2C%20etc.). Y además, podrías usar `loops` para esto.

- **`for`**:

```
for i in range(1, 5 + 1):
    print(i)
```

**Resultado**:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

```
for numero in range(1, 5 + 1):
    locals()["variable_" + str(numero)] = 'Ejemplo' + str(numero)

print(variable_1)
print(variable_2)
print(variable_3)
print(variable_4)
print(variable_5)
```

**Resultado**:

```
Ejemplo1
Ejemplo2
Ejemplo3
Ejemplo4
Ejemplo5
```

Locals realmente lo que hace es devolver lo que llaman "local symbol table" donde almacena información del programa (e.g: nombre del fichero, variables, etc).

**Por ejemplo**:

```
variable = 'Ejemplo'
variable_2 = 'Ejemplo 2'
print(locals())
```

En mí caso, **devuelve lo siguiente**:

```
{
'__name__': '__main__', 
'__doc__': None, 
'__package__': None, 
'__loader__': <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f59562de350>, 
'__spec__': None, 
'__annotations__': {}, 
'__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, 
'__file__': 'create_variables_on_the_fly.py', 
'__cached__': None, 
'variable': 'Ejemplo', 
'variable_2': 'Ejemplo 2'
}
```

Donde podrás ver las variables. De allí a que puedas crearlas "al vuelo" usando el método `locals`.

Otro ejemplo sería el siguiente:

Suponiendo que tengo el siguiente diccionario:

```
data = {
    '1' : 'Primero',
    '2' : 'Segundo',
    '3' : 'Tecero'
}
```

Si recorro cada una de sus `key`:

```
for key in data:
    print(key)
```

**Obtengo lo siguiente**:

```
1
2
3
```

Por lo que podría jugar con esto para crear estas variables según los valores de cada una de las keys del diccionario:

```
for key in data:
    locals()["variable_" + str(key)] = data[key]

print(locals())
```

**Resultado**:

```
{
...
'data': {'1': 'Primero', '2': 'Segundo', '3': 'Tecero'}, 'key': '3', 'variable_1': 'Primero', 
'variable_2': 'Segundo', 
'variable_3': 'Tecero'
}
```

Comment: El problema se resuelve naturalmente usando listas. Ofrecer *hacks* como `locals`, `eval` y similares es pasarle una motosierra para partir el pan. Por supuesto, `locals`y `eval` tienen usos legitimos, pero no en este caso.

Comment: Efectivamente. De allí el primer párrafo de la respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar el siguiente codigo

```
dic ={}

for i in range (0,70): 
    dic2={'nombre_'+str(i+1):i+1} 
    dic.update(dic2)
```

##Esta primera salida lo que genera es el diccionario, usando ayuda de la funcion `update()` para añadir elementos nuevos al diccionario con un diccionario auxiliar, en caso de quererlo usar más de una vez se podría crear una funcion que tenga un solo parametro.

```
for key in dic: 
    print(key,'=',dic[key])
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este seria un ejemplo de la salida.